# Subdomain not working due to Options -Indexes

Tags: .htaccess

Subdomain display 403 error due to "Options -Indexes" in .htaccess.
How to denied directory listing while permitting to Subdomain directory to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**QUICK ANSWER**

> Define your `DirectoryIndex` in the httpd.conf

**EXAMPLE**

```
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
</IfModule>
```

**AFTER THAT**

- Add an `index.php` or `index.html` file on your subdirectory.
- The file you are adding must be the file you want to see when you access the subdirectory. The name & extension must match the values defined in the `DirectoryIndex` directive.